# Among xerophyte plants, which one grow faster and consume water the least?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, adaptation, agriculture

In an effort to select for the most suitable plants to possibly colonise desert and stop its expansion,

what would be the xerophyte plants that grow the faster and expand on surface, while using the less water and produce a maximum of biomass?

Comment: I don't think that there has been a comparison done among xerophytes as to which one grows fastest and which one the slowest. A list of fast growing trees can be found [here](http://www.hotgardens.net/fast_growing_trees.htm) and [here](http://www.hotgardens.net/leafy_trees_for_cooling_shade.htm).

Comment: [Allan Savory](http://www.ted.com/talks/allan_savory_how_to_green_the_world_s_deserts_and_reverse_climate_change) recommends carefully managing grazing animals to promote grass growth. While his methods have been [criticized](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/food/2013/04/allan_savory_s_ted_talk_is_wrong_and_the_benefits_of_holistic_grazing_have.html), it hasn't seemed to damage our farm, where we raise cattle through intensively managed grazing, but our land isn't subject to desertification. I doubt you could solve desertification with a monoculture of xerophytes though.